# How to get remote interface in ejb over ssl

Tags: ssl, jboss, active-directory, ejb, remoteobject

we recently moved to ad authentication and also turned on SSL for a web app and there a process that runs on a separate machine and it connects to the jboss server on production and tries make a remote call. How do i make a secure remote call work? Please let me know if i need to provide any additional details.

I am using EJB 1.1

Answer (score 2):

The EJB has to be exported with an SSL client socket factory, which is a configuration step at the server. There isn't anything required at the client end.

Comment: How do i do that? any documentation you could point me to, which would help?. I am unable to find a proper guide to follow. Thanks